# How to verify strings are in a certain date format?

Tags: c#

How can I verify that strings are in the format `"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.mmm"`?

For example:

```
12.01.2011 13:26:10.000
13.05.2010 22:30:20.000
```

should be accepted, others should be rejected.  I want to be able to do something like:

```
string c = "12.01.2011 13:26:10.000";

if (string.CompareFormat(c))
{
    // do something
}
else
{
    // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TryParseExact`:

```
        string format = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff";
        string c = "12.01.2011 13:26:10.000";
        CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");

        DateTime result;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(c, format, enUS, DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Right Format");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong Format");                
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try parsing it with [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e.aspx)...

Answer (score 1):

Use [`TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) with your required date format. This will make sure that only this specific format is matched, in contrast to the normal `Parse`/`TryParse`.

```
string c = "12.01.2011 13:26:10.000";
DateTime result;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(c, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result)) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  try
            {
                string c = "12.01.2011 13:26:10.000";
                DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(c.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Rejected
            }
```

when it is not in datetime format exception will occur

or can use TryParse

```
string c = "12.01.2011 13:26:10.000";
                DateTime dt;
                if(!DateTime.TryParse(c,out dt))
                {
                //rejected
                }
```

Comment: @derya: what do you mean too slow? What are you performance criteria?

Comment: I have more than 84000 data. So while program tries to parse via this way, it takes more than 2 minutes.. Ok, now I am trying TryParse already ;)

Comment: I tried this, but there is something wrong :

if (DateTime.TryParse(c, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", result))
                    {
 
                    }
result type is DateTime..

Comment: @derya, look at my answer for a working `TryParseExact` solution.

Comment: try this DateTime.TryParseExact(c, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result)